# how to put nestjs "reflect metadata" in swagger fields

Tags: swagger, nestjs, metadata, reflect

controller with guard and metadata

```
@UseGuards(RightsGuard)
@Rights('users')
@Level('write')
@Get('/clearAuthSuccess')
async clearAuthSuccess(): Promise<DefaultMessageDto> {
        return this.authService.clearAuthSuccess()
}
```

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: The only thing you can do is https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/introduction

Comment: omg.captain obvious. but it has already been tested